# I am Global Admin in Azure but I cannot see any Billing Scope

Tags: azure, azure-billing

I have a client that gave me Global Admin to set up a new infrastructure but I cannot see any Billing Scope, therefore I cannot create subscriptions or do much at all.

In another client I can see a tick box over the Billing Scopes that allows me to see all Billing Scopes as Global Admins but the tickbox is not there in this client.

The current owner of the account is the finance director of the company, therefore I don't have easy access to his account.

Any ideas?